# Doesn't show dialog

Tags: java, awt, frame

```
import    java.awt.*;
import    java.awt.event.*;
import    java.lang.*;

public  class Party {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.printf("Start\n");
        Frame  f = new Frame();
        Label  l = new Label("Party over here!");
        Button b = new Button("You bet") ;
        Button C = new Button("Shoot me");
        Panel  p = new Panel();
        p.add(l);
        System.out.printf("End\n");
    }  
}
```

Why don't I get the dialog? Something missing in the example?

Comment: Well it seems you have made a frame, and a label and a button, and put something on a panel. But did you show the frame?

Comment: Probably because there is no trace of Dialog in your Java class. There is a frame, but it's never made visible anywhere. BTW, forget about AWT. It's old and obsolete. Use Swing instead. Google for Java swing tutorial.

Comment: SO isn't code generator, read [Oracle turorial about Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: I would suggest skipping AWT and moving straight to Swing - IMHO - Swing is a much more flexible API

Comment: `import    java.lang.*;`  Does not need to be imported.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.printf("Start\n");
    Frame  f = new Frame();
    Label  l = new Label("Party over here!");
    Button b = new Button("You bet") ;
    Button C = new Button("Shoot me");
    Panel  p = new Panel();
    p.add(l);
    f.add(p);
    f.add(b);
    f.add(c);
    f.setVisible(true);//<-- make it visible...
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

I think you need to read some more basics about the java GUI, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The book, in that example, comments, after, `new Panel()` line:

`//more code here...`

That means that the code is non necessarily functional.

By adding a line `f.setVisible(true);` you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your code:

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: hmmm but nothing is added to awt.Frame, isn't it

Comment: @mKorbel it should work, try to set size `f.setSize(500,500);`

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you have made a frame, and a label and a button, and put something on a panel. But did you show the frame?

Use `f.setVisible(true);`

And if you want to use a frame I suggest you use JFrame.

But you specified you wanted a dialog to show up, and this is how you do so:

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");`

Look here for more info on dialogs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#overview